# PL/SQL: Need help creating calculated columns based on conditions. to be done in select query

Tags: oracle, plsql, conditional-statements, calculated-columns

I am trying to count all the distinct ids based on conditions. But I am unable to figure out where I am going wrong with the syntax. The logic is

```
COUNTD(IF ([column_name1] = 1) THEN [DATAPAGEID] END)
```

This is the formula I used in Tableau. However when writing it in a PL/SQL query as

```
Select FT.NAME, COUNT(DISTINCT FT.pageID IF FT."column_name" = 1 )  
as total_expected
FROM 
( Sub Query) FT
Group by FT.Name 
Order by FT.Name
```

Needless to say its throwing errors. Now I can write separate queries which can give me each number using a where condition. For example, if I wanted a count of distinct pageid where column_name1 = 1, I would write something like this

```
        Select FT.SITENAME, COUNT(DISTINCT DATAPAGEID) as Datapage
       from 
          (sub query)
       WHERE FT."column_name" = 1
```

but the problem with that is that I have other calculated columns in the query which will all need to be part of the same row. To illustrate here's what the table would look like

```
       name      Calculated_Column1   Calculated_Column2   Calculated_column3
      abc        781                  811                    96.54%
      pqr        600                  800                    75.00%
```

where calculated_column3 is the result of 781/811. Therefore I can't have a new query for each column. I thought using an if condition when calculating columns will solve this, but I can't get the syntax right somehow.

Therefore, I need to know how can I create conditional calculated columns within the select query. If I have not explained this well, please let me know and I will try to clarify further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CASE block inside the `count (DISTINCT )` as shown.

```
SELECT FT.NAME,
  COUNT(DISTINCT
  CASE
    WHEN DATAPAGEID = 1
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END ) Calculated_Column1,
  COUNT(DISTINCT
  CASE
    WHEN DATAPAGEID = 2
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END ) Calculated_Column2,
  ( COUNT(DISTINCT
  CASE
    WHEN DATAPAGEID = 1
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END ) / COUNT(DISTINCT
  CASE
    WHEN DATAPAGEID = 2
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END ) ) * 100||'%' Calculated_Column3
FROM
  ( SELECT 'abc' name, 1 DATAPAGEID FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc' name, 1 DATAPAGEID FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'pqr' name, 2 DATAPAGEID FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'pqr' name, 2 DATAPAGEID FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'pqr' name, 3 DATAPAGEID FROM dual
  ) FT
GROUP BY FT.Name
ORDER BY FT.Name;
```

Output is

```
abc 1   1   100%
pqr 1   2   50%
```